# Word/phrase request for a unique speech style

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What do we call, when a person pronounce a few words in some unique way of his own, i.e., a wrong pronunciation and this is not because of any speech disorder. It's just that for them such words are tongue-twister.

This usually happens in case of speaking a foreign language, and speaker cannot avoid mispronouncing some words.

I can use "dialect" or "speech style" to say a sentence like this:

> this person has a speech style of his own.

I don't want to use words like: mispronounce/wrong/peculiar.

Do we have a name for this type of speaking manner, or any suitable phrase to describe this situation?

Comment: Like an [idiolect](https://www.google.com/search?q=idiolect+definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Qhb4WM2xFMyw8wfXlJH4AQ)?

Comment: Welcome to ELU, aiaa.  Did you do any research to find an answer to your question?  If so you should tell us about it.  In any case it looks like you've got a good one-word answer to a single-word request from Cascabel: idiolect.  Look it up.

Comment: "Idiolect" is a perfect word here. @Cascabel Please submit this as an answer and I'd be more than happy to accept it as an answer.

Comment: @Xanne Yes, I did some research on my part. I found a word - "parlance", but I wasn't quite sure of its aptness here.

Comment: I think you meant that they pronounce "**a** few words" their own way and have edited your question to insert "a". Feel free to roll it back if you really intended to say that they pronounce *almost no* words that way (in which case, you might say they have a fairly *standard* pronunciation).

Comment: @Lawrence: Yes, I meant "a few words". Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**idiolect**

> - The speech patterns unique to an individual. 
>     Notes: 1. These speech patterns consist of the diction, idioms, ***and pronunciations that are unique*** to any individual, hence everyone

[Online Dictionary of Language Terminology](http://www.odlt.org/)

Every person has an idiolect that is influenced by a range of factors including class, family, place of birth, friends, lifestyle, etc. Idiolects usually evolve through contact with other idiolects, and will change over the course of a person´s lifetime.